# JAVA Read binary file if matches with Scanner

Tags: java, binary, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream, matcher

I'm a student and I'm doing an exercise that:
-1 Writes 3 people with 5 personal information in a binary file
-2 Reads a binary file with
-2.1 Reading all the file
-2.2 Reading user(s) that match with the scanner input

If I read all the file

```
case 1:
                            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);

                            int content;

                            while ((content = fileIn.read()) != -1) {
                                System.out.print((char) content);
                            }
                            System.out.println("\n");

                            break;
```

All works perfect, the output looks like this:
pepe villuela balaguer catalan 34
pepa diaz sanjose marciano 56
pepe chula carta marciano 56

But I'm confused, due my little experience with binary files, that how to work with:

- How to store the read data from the binary file
- How to make a matcher and pattern of that data.
  *Mi plan was to read first the binary data, and somehow, comparing that data with variables.
  The problem is that "String invent2" is reading in vertical, and matcher is not recognising the pattern.

Sorry if this mesagge is unstructured, so many hours thinking*
This is my failing code:

```
                            case 2:
                            System.out.println("Introduce the name of the user(s)...");
                            sc.nextLine();
                            name = sc.nextLine();

                            FileInputStream fileIn2 = new FileInputStream(file);int content2;
                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z]*)\s([a-z]*)\s([a-z]*)\s([a-z]*)\s(\\d*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);                                                           

                            while ((content2 = fileIn2.read()) != -1) {
                                String invent2 = String.valueOf((char) content2);                            
                                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(invent2);
                                matcher.find();

                                String nameField = matcher.group(1);
                                String surnameField = matcher.group(2);
                                String cityField = matcher.group(3);
                                String nationField = matcher.group(4);
                                String ageField = matcher.group(5);

                                if (name.equals(nameField)) {
                                    System.out.print("Name=" + nameField + " Surname=" + surnameField
                                            + " City=" + cityField + " Nationality=" + nationField + " Age=" + ageField + "\n");
                                }
                                System.out.println("\n");

                                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

> pepe villuela balaguer catalan 34 pepa diaz sanjose marciano 56 pepe chula carta marciano 56

That's not binary data. Or rather, **all files** (and `System.in`) itself **is** binary data. Text is also stored as binary data, using an encoding. You are reading in one byte and casting it to a char which only works for basic ASCII (a-zA-Z, space, dollar, underscore, not much more than that, certainly not for ç, é, etc).

Point is, your text file contains characters / you are interpreting them as characters, thus the term 'binary data' doesn't apply.

If your data is indeed exactly as I pasted above, then you just want to make a scanner out of your file:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(thatFile), "UTF-8")) {
  while (sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("> " + sc.next());
  }
}
```

Would print:

```
> pepe
> villuela
> balaguer
```

and so on.

You can feed these strings into a list to store them, through a regexp tool to match them, whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment.
I'm not sure If I'm understanding what you said.
I made one option on the menu to write text in "binary data" something like this:

"get all the data", byte [ ] thing=person1.printProfile.getBytes(StaandarCharset.UTF_8);

Comment: FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
                            DataOutputStream dataOS = new DataOutputStream(fileOS);
                            dataOS.write(arrayDatos);
And try to read it later
That means that that text is not binary? It's something like encoded text?
My plan was to read the "binary data" and try to work with it in text format which I control better.
It's hard to express in this text box. Sorry

Comment: All file data is binary. Even text files are. To write text (strings) to a file, you must turn them into bytes, and that means a charset encoding is applied. To read a file means reading bytes. If those are meant to represent text, you convert them to a string.. by applying a charset encoding.

Comment: `new Scanner(new File(thatFile), "UTF-8")` is one way: That reads a file by 'turning it into text on the fly', and given that conversion from strings to bytes and vice versa always involves a charset encoding, best be explicit and specify it so nobody gets confused, hence, `"UTF-8"` being passed as parameter.

Comment: I really appreciate your time! I have to investivage a bit more aboute this subject. Thanks a lot,.